How do I change the position of the zoom buttons in the TWebLeafletMaps component?
By default, the buttons are aligned top left as can be seen here:

Normally when using Leaflet in JavaScript, then when initializing the leaflet map, you're able to set a position like shown here:
//disable zoomControl when initializing map (which is topleft by default)
var map = L.map("map", {
    zoomControl: false
    //... other options
});

//add zoom control with your options
L.control.zoom({
     position:'topright'
}).addTo(map);

But in Delphi, I'm not the person initializing the leaflet map. That is happening in the background automatically.
So, how can I move the zoom buttons in the TWebLeafletMaps component to a different location using Delphi programming code?
